# Copy a file using a makefile at runtime

Tags: makefile, copy, cp

*I used to compile my programs with batch scripts on windows but I recently discovered makefiles which are much more efficient.*

I had this line in my `.bat` file that copied some dlls *to* the current directory at runtime and it worked perfectly.

```
copy C:\lib\glfw\glfw.dll
```

I tried the same line in my makefile and even tried the alternative `cp` but my terminal prints this error even tho ***the file is IN the location I specified***

```
process_begin: CreateProcess(NULL, copy C:\lib\glfw\glfw.dll, ...) failed
make (e=2): The system cannot find the file specified.
make: *** [core.exe] Error 2
```

Here is the full makefile that I am using. Mind you, absent the copy line it works like a charm.. what am I doing wrong or is this possible?

```
EXEC = core.exe
OBJS = src/obp.o

CC = g++

CFLAGS  = -W -Wall
LIBS    = -lSOIL -lglew32 -lglfw -lopengl32
LDFLAGS =

$(EXEC): $(OBJS)
    $(CC) $(LDFLAGS) -o $@ $(OBJS) $(LIBS)
    copy C:\lib\glfw\glfw.dll

clean:
    rm -f $(EXEC) $(OBJS) *~
```

Comment: Is it maybe the `copy` that can not be found? How come you are using `rm`, can it find that? Are you running this in an `MSYS` environment?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like you are running this from an `MSYS` (or `MinGW`) environment, which does not know about `copy`. Instead, you can use

```
cp C:\lib\glfw\glfw.dll .
```

If you want to avoid the *nix like `cp`, then you could use `xcopy` as follows:

```
xcopy //Y C:\lib\glfw\glfw.dll
```

Note the double `//` which is required to escape the `/`.

Or you could run this in a regular `MS-DOS` environment, in which case your `clean` target will not work because `rm` will not be found and you should use `del`.

With your current setup, any built-in `DOS` command will not be found. See [Choosing the shell](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Choosing-the-Shell.html) to read about how `make` determines which shell to use.

Comment: i was running it in an dos environ from start and cp doesn't work either.

Comment: I can think of nothing but doing some debugging steps. Do you know where it gets `rm` from? Could you do `where rm` in your command prompt? (This only makes sense if you have a somewhat newer Windows version that supports `where`). Also, what are your values of `$(SHELL)` and `$(MAKESHELL)`? You can print them from your `makefile` using something like `$(info SHELL = $(SHELL))` at the top.

Comment: dunno if this helps but $(info SHELL...) returns SHELL = C:/MinGW/msys/1.0/bin//sh.exe and where rm prints C:\MinGW\msys\1.0\bin\rm.exe

Comment: Yes, this does help. So you are running an `MSYS` shell, without realizing it. You can see that from the paths you just printed. This means that my original answer *should* work. What error do you get when using `cp`? Did you not forget to add the period to the end of the `cp` command?

Comment: X_x.. i forgot the `.` :D.. it works. thanks.. what does it do btw?

Comment: `cp` is the *nix variant of `copy` and it is used as `cp <source> <destination>`. The destination is mandatory, and the `.` indicates the current directory is the destination. I updated the answer to give you some more information.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to double the backslashes in order for `make` to understand what you want:

```
copy c:\\lib\\glfw\\glfw.dll
```

Make comes from a Unix background where the file separator is `/`, so it's sometimes a bit awkward to use it in a Windows environment.

Comment: it prints the new line with the \\ but the same error as above.

Comment: Perhaps you could try using `/`, but I'm not sure whether the `copy` command will understand that.

Comment: i use scons to build blender but no. i wanted to keep this as simple as possible.
*edit - i might just try that.