# Makefile error on windows

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I am trying to run makefile on windows7. I have added make.exe in windows path variable and 
I am trying to run "make -f makefile.txt" but it shows error

```
"cc -o edit main.o kbd.o command.o display.o insert.o search.o files.o utils.o
process_begin: CreateProcess(NULL, cc -o edit main.o kbd.o command.o display.o i
nsert.o search.o files.o utils.o, ...) failed.
make (e=2): The system cannot find the file specified.
make: *** [edit] Error"
```

Please help me as i am new to make concept.

Comment: What is that "edit" there? Is that a file? An option you tried to pass?

Comment: Do all of those object files exist? (And why are you starting with something that requires *eight* modules?)

Answer (score 8):

It is not sufficient to just add `make.exe` to the path. Your problem is that `cc` can not be found while trying to make the target called `edit`. Try running the same command from an MinGW/MSYS or CygWin shell, depending on how you installed this. That will most likely give you the proper environment to use `make` with this makefile.

This issue is similar to [copy a file using a makefile at runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11750983/1380680)

Comment: Thanks for your feedback.... now i have used GCC arm-tool chain it shows below error                                                 arm-none-eabi-gcc -o edit main.o kbd.o command.o display.o insert.o search.o fil
es.o utils.o
c:/shiavng/gcctoolchain/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/4.6.2/../../../../arm-none-
eabi/lib\libc.a(lib_a-exit.o): In function `exit':
exit.c:(.text.exit+0x2c): undefined reference to `_exit'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [edit] Error 1

Comment: I do not think that this new problem is related to the original issue -- in any case I do not know the answer. You are better of posing it as a new question with the right tags.

Answer (score 2):

To make it work install [MinGW](http://www.mingw.org/) (mingw-get-setup.exe) which will install mingw-get.exe utility that could be used to install all needed build tools.

With C:\Mingw\bin (or whatever path selected during installation) on $PATH type in console:

```
$ mingw-get.exe gcc g++ msys-base
```

After it finishes MSYS env will be available with all necessary tools (execute C:\MinGW\msys\1.0\msys.bat to open it)

Now you can use *make* like in unix envs.

```
Mike@Mike-PC ~
$ make
make: *** No targets specified and no makefile found.  Stop.
```

---

If it is not enough install *mingw32-make* as well with *mingw-get*.

Answer (score 0):

For some things on windows you'll want to install coreutils. I had this issue for nordic nrf micro issues with make but it's the same error

http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/coreutils.htm

Landed here on a re-install of windows scratching head. This was the fix as it adds a bunch of useful commands to windows. Like why did "ls" work on my old drive and not the new one... answer core-utils. Why does it build everywhere and not here -- core-utils. Hope this helps someone in another 8 years.