# make command is not working in QT command prompt

Tags: c++, qt, command-line, makefile

I am using QT 4.6.2 with MinGW 4.4. I have used

```
qmake –project
qmake example.pro
```

They are successfully executed. But While using make command from QT command prompt, giving me the following error,

```
C:\Users\musharrat.khan\Desktop\example>make
mingw32-make -f Makefile.Debug
mingw32-make[1]: Entering directory `C:/Users/musharrat.khan/Desktop/example'
g++ -c -g -frtti -fexceptions -mthreads -Wall -DUNICODE -DQT_LARGEFILE_SUPPORT -DQT_DLL -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -DQT_THREAD_SUPPORT -DQT_NEEDS_QMAIN -I"..\..
\..\..\Qt\4.6.2\include\QtCore" -I"..\..\..\..\Qt\4.6.2\include\QtGui" -I"..\..\..\..\Qt\4.6.2\include" -I"." -I"..\..\..\..\Qt\4.6.2\include\ActiveQt" -I"debug
" -I"..\..\..\..\Qt\4.6.2\mkspecs\win32-g++" -o debug\example.o example.cc
process_begin: CreateProcess(C:\Users\MUSHAR~1.KHA\AppData\Local\Temp\make4484-1.bat, C:\Users\MUSHAR~1.KHA\AppData\Local\Temp\make4484-1.bat, ...) failed.
make (e=2): The system cannot find the file specified.
mingw32-make[1]: *** [debug/example.o] Error 2
mingw32-make[1]: Leaving directory `C:/Users/musharrat.khan/Desktop/example'
mingw32-make: *** [debug] Error 2
```

Are there any solution for this? I am using windows 8.1.

Comment: Is g++ installed and in your current PATH ? Looks like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12991339/makefile-error-on-windows

Comment: Looks like your user name is too difficult for MinGW

Comment: Yes, g++ is installed and PATH is also set.