# Make error: make (e=2): The system cannot find the file specified

Tags: c, eclipse, makefile, nrf51

I am trying to compile a c project on a new windows PC, but when I run make I get:

```
D:\Eclipse_Workspace\project>make
#@make -f  makefile -C ./  -e cleanobj
process_begin: CreateProcess(NULL, #@make -f makefile -C ./ -e cleanobj, ...) failed.
make (e=2): The system cannot find the file specified.
make: *** [all] Fejl 2
```

On my other PC the project is compiling just fine.
Also "Fejl 2" is danish for "Error 2", have no idea why that is in danish when the rest is english.

EDIT: 
Here is the makefile (it's rather long)

```
PROJECT_NAME := ble_app_hrs_s110_pca10028

export OUTPUT_FILENAME
#MAKEFILE_NAME := $(CURDIR)/$(word $(words $(MAKEFILE_LIST)),$(MAKEFILE_LIST))
MAKEFILE_NAME := $(MAKEFILE_LIST)
MAKEFILE_DIR := $(dir $(MAKEFILE_NAME) ) 

TEMPLATE_PATH = nrf51_sdk/toolchain/gcc
ifeq ($(OS),Windows_NT)
include $(TEMPLATE_PATH)/Makefile.windows
else
include $(TEMPLATE_PATH)/Makefile.posix
endif

MK := mkdir
RM := rm -rf

#echo suspend
ifeq ("$(VERBOSE)","1")
NO_ECHO := 
else
NO_ECHO := @
endif

# Toolchain commands
CC              := "$(GNU_INSTALL_ROOT)/bin/$(GNU_PREFIX)-gcc"
AS              := "$(GNU_INSTALL_ROOT)/bin/$(GNU_PREFIX)-as"
AR              := "$(GNU_INSTALL_ROOT)/bin/$(GNU_PREFIX)-ar" -r
LD              := "$(GNU_INSTALL_ROOT)/bin/$(GNU_PREFIX)-ld"
NM              := "$(GNU_INSTALL_ROOT)/bin/$(GNU_PREFIX)-nm"
OBJDUMP         := "$(GNU_INSTALL_ROOT)/bin/$(GNU_PREFIX)-objdump"
OBJCOPY         := "$(GNU_INSTALL_ROOT)/bin/$(GNU_PREFIX)-objcopy"
SIZE            := "$(GNU_INSTALL_ROOT)/bin/$(GNU_PREFIX)-size"

#function for removing duplicates in a list
remduplicates = $(strip $(if $1,$(firstword $1) $(call remduplicates,$(filter-out $(firstword $1),$1))))

#source common to all targets
C_SOURCE_FILES += \
nrf51_sdk/drivers_nrf/rtc/nrf_drv_rtc.c \
Drivers/NRF51_BLEDriver.c \
(..... a lot more files ....)

#assembly files common to all targets
ASM_SOURCE_FILES  = nrf51_sdk/toolchain/gcc/gcc_startup_nrf51.s

#includes common to all targets
INC_PATHS  = -I Application/
(..... a lot more include paths.......)

OBJECT_DIRECTORY = _build
LISTING_DIRECTORY =$(OBJECT_DIRECTORY)
OUTPUT_BINARY_DIRECTORY =$(OBJECT_DIRECTORY)

# Sorting removes duplicates
BUILD_DIRECTORIES := $(sort $(OBJECT_DIRECTORY) $(OUTPUT_BINARY_DIRECTORY) $(LISTING_DIRECTORY) )

#flags common to all targets
CFLAGS  = -DSOFTDEVICE_PRESENT
CFLAGS += -DNRF51
CFLAGS += -DS110
CFLAGS += -DBOARD_PCA10028
CFLAGS += -DBLE_STACK_SUPPORT_REQD
CFLAGS += -mcpu=cortex-m0
CFLAGS += -mthumb -mabi=aapcs --std=gnu99
CFLAGS += -Wall -O0 -g3
CFLAGS += -mfloat-abi=soft
# keep every function in separate section. This will allow linker to dump unused functions
CFLAGS += -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -fno-strict-aliasing
#CFLAGS += -flto -fno-builtin

# keep every function in separate section. This will allow linker to dump unused functions
LDFLAGS += -Xlinker -Map=$(LISTING_DIRECTORY)/$(OUTPUT_FILENAME).map
LDFLAGS += -mthumb -mabi=aapcs -L $(TEMPLATE_PATH) -T$(LINKER_SCRIPT)
LDFLAGS += -mcpu=cortex-m0
# let linker to dump unused sections
LDFLAGS += -Wl,--gc-sections
# use newlib in nano version
LDFLAGS += --specs=nano.specs -lc -lnosys

# Assembler flags
ASMFLAGS += -x assembler-with-cpp
ASMFLAGS += -DSOFTDEVICE_PRESENT
ASMFLAGS += -DNRF51
ASMFLAGS += -DS110
ASMFLAGS += -DBOARD_PCA10028
ASMFLAGS += -DBLE_STACK_SUPPORT_REQD
#default target - first one defined
#default: clean nrf51422_xxac_s110

#building all targets
all: #clean
    #$(NO_ECHO)$(MAKE) -f $(MAKEFILE_NAME) -C $(MAKEFILE_DIR) -e cleanobj
    $(NO_ECHO)$(MAKE) -f $(MAKEFILE_NAME) -C $(MAKEFILE_DIR) -e nrf51422_xxac_s110 

#target for printing all targets
help:
    @echo following targets are available:
    @echo   nrf51422_xxac_s110
    @echo   flash_softdevice


C_SOURCE_FILE_NAMES = $(notdir $(C_SOURCE_FILES))
C_PATHS = $(call remduplicates, $(dir $(C_SOURCE_FILES) ) )
C_OBJECTS = $(addprefix $(OBJECT_DIRECTORY)/, $(C_SOURCE_FILE_NAMES:.c=.o) )

ASM_SOURCE_FILE_NAMES = $(notdir $(ASM_SOURCE_FILES))
ASM_PATHS = $(call remduplicates, $(dir $(ASM_SOURCE_FILES) ))
ASM_OBJECTS = $(addprefix $(OBJECT_DIRECTORY)/, $(ASM_SOURCE_FILE_NAMES:.s=.o) )

vpath %.c $(C_PATHS)
vpath %.s $(ASM_PATHS)

OBJECTS = $(C_OBJECTS) $(ASM_OBJECTS)

nrf51422_xxac_s110: OUTPUT_FILENAME := nrf51422_xxac_s110
nrf51422_xxac_s110: LINKER_SCRIPT=ble_app_hrs_gcc_nrf51.ld
nrf51422_xxac_s110: $(BUILD_DIRECTORIES) $(OBJECTS)
    @echo Linking target: $(OUTPUT_FILENAME).out
    $(NO_ECHO)$(CC) $(LDFLAGS) $(OBJECTS) $(LIBS) -o $(OUTPUT_BINARY_DIRECTORY)/$(OUTPUT_FILENAME).out
    $(NO_ECHO)$(MAKE) -f $(MAKEFILE_NAME) -C $(MAKEFILE_DIR) -e finalize

## Create build directories
$(BUILD_DIRECTORIES):
    echo $(MAKEFILE_NAME)
    $(MK) $@

# Create objects from C SRC files
$(OBJECT_DIRECTORY)/%.o: %.c
    @echo Compiling file: $(notdir $<)
    @echo arm-none-eabi-gcc $(CFLAGS) $(INC_PATHS) -c -o $@ $<
    $(NO_ECHO)$(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(INC_PATHS) -c -o $@ $<

# Assemble files
$(OBJECT_DIRECTORY)/%.o: %.s
    @echo Compiling file: $(notdir $<)
    $(NO_ECHO)$(CC) $(ASMFLAGS) $(INC_PATHS) -c -o $@ $<


# Link
$(OUTPUT_BINARY_DIRECTORY)/$(OUTPUT_FILENAME).out: $(BUILD_DIRECTORIES) $(OBJECTS)
    @echo Linking target: $(OUTPUT_FILENAME).out
    $(NO_ECHO)$(CC) $(LDFLAGS) $(OBJECTS) $(LIBS) -o $(OUTPUT_BINARY_DIRECTORY)/$(OUTPUT_FILENAME).out


## Create binary .bin file from the .out file
$(OUTPUT_BINARY_DIRECTORY)/$(OUTPUT_FILENAME).bin: $(OUTPUT_BINARY_DIRECTORY)/$(OUTPUT_FILENAME).out
    @echo Preparing: $(OUTPUT_FILENAME).bin
    $(NO_ECHO)$(OBJCOPY) -O binary $(OUTPUT_BINARY_DIRECTORY)/$(OUTPUT_FILENAME).out $(OUTPUT_BINARY_DIRECTORY)/$(OUTPUT_FILENAME).bin

## Create binary .hex file from the .out file
$(OUTPUT_BINARY_DIRECTORY)/$(OUTPUT_FILENAME).hex: $(OUTPUT_BINARY_DIRECTORY)/$(OUTPUT_FILENAME).out
    @echo Preparing: $(OUTPUT_FILENAME).hex
    $(NO_ECHO)$(OBJCOPY) -O ihex $(OUTPUT_BINARY_DIRECTORY)/$(OUTPUT_FILENAME).out $(OUTPUT_BINARY_DIRECTORY)/$(OUTPUT_FILENAME).hex

finalize: genbin genhex echosize

genbin:
    @echo Preparing: $(OUTPUT_FILENAME).bin
    $(NO_ECHO)$(OBJCOPY) -O binary $(OUTPUT_BINARY_DIRECTORY)/$(OUTPUT_FILENAME).out $(OUTPUT_BINARY_DIRECTORY)/$(OUTPUT_FILENAME).bin

## Create binary .hex file from the .out file
genhex: 
    @echo Preparing: $(OUTPUT_FILENAME).hex
    $(NO_ECHO)$(OBJCOPY) -O ihex $(OUTPUT_BINARY_DIRECTORY)/$(OUTPUT_FILENAME).out $(OUTPUT_BINARY_DIRECTORY)/$(OUTPUT_FILENAME).hex

echosize:
    -@echo ""
    $(NO_ECHO)$(SIZE) $(OUTPUT_BINARY_DIRECTORY)/$(OUTPUT_FILENAME).out
    -@echo ""

clean:
    $(RM) $(BUILD_DIRECTORIES)

cleanobj:
    $(RM) $(BUILD_DIRECTORIES)/*.o

flash: $(MAKECMDGOALS)
    @echo Flashing: $(OUTPUT_BINARY_DIRECTORY)/$<.hex
    nrfjprog --reset --program $(OUTPUT_BINARY_DIRECTORY)/$<.hex)

## Flash softdevice
flash_softdevice: 
    @echo Flashing: s110_softdevice.hex
    nrfjprog --reset --program nrf51_sdk/softdevice/s110/hex/s110_softdevice.hex
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Makefile error on windows](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12991339/makefile-error-on-windows)

Comment: Well, it seems make can't find itself. Uh???

Comment: Can we see what is inside this makefile? If we can't, we won't be able to help you.

Comment: @jdarthenay check edit

Comment: @Jolle what happens if you enter command `where make` in your dos console? Also if you know how to invite me in a chat room do it...

Comment: @jdarthenay it says: C:\Program Files (x86)\GnuWin32\bin\make.exe .. Chatroom? no idea - do you have a link for guide maybe?

Comment: @can you enter command `make --version` in both systems to see if they are different?

Comment: Both is GNU Make 3.81 :(

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/109384/discussion-between-jdarthenay-and-jolle).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In make, every line indented by a TAB character (in a "recipe context") will be passed as a command to the shell.  *Nothing* about such a line will be interpreted by make, except for `$`.

In particular for you, the `#` character is not special to make in this context and doesn't introduce a make comment line.  So in this rule:

```
all: #clean
        #$(NO_ECHO)$(MAKE) -f $(MAKEFILE_NAME) -C $(MAKEFILE_DIR) -e cleanobj
        $(NO_ECHO)$(MAKE) -f $(MAKEFILE_NAME) -C $(MAKEFILE_DIR) -e nrf51422_xxac_s110
```

the first line is not commented out; it's a command line that begins with a `#` character and make will ask the system to run that command.  Clearly such a command doesn't exist on your system.

If you want to comment out recipe lines in make, you should always put the comment character at the beginning of the line not after the TAB:

```
all: #clean
#       $(NO_ECHO)$(MAKE) -f $(MAKEFILE_NAME) -C $(MAKEFILE_DIR) -e cleanobj
        $(NO_ECHO)$(MAKE) -f $(MAKEFILE_NAME) -C $(MAKEFILE_DIR) -e nrf51422_xxac_s110
```

Comment: Ah did the job! Now I'm getting another error, but it's some files it can't find, that I'll figure out myself. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Just a comment  -  I struggled for a very long time until I realised RM was set to `rm -f`  and there was no way that works on Windows. Set it to `del` and all was fine